# Extract information from an Excel (by updating arrays) with Excel / Python

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis

I have an Excel file with thousands of columns on the following format:

| Member No. | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 25 | 60 | -30 |
|  | -69 | 38 | 68 |
|  | 45 | 2 | 43 |
| 1001 | 24 | 55 | 79 |
|  | 4 | -7 | 89 |
|  | 78 | 51 | -2 |
| 1002 | 45 | -55 | 149 |
|  | 94 | 77 | -985 |
|  | -2 | 559 | 56 |

I need a way such that I shall get a new table with the absolute maximum value from each column. In this example, something like:

| Member No. | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 69 | 60 | 68 |
| 1001 | 78 | 55 | 89 |
| 1002 | 94 | 559 | 985 |

I have tried it in Excel (with using `VLOOKUP` for finding the "Member Number" in the first row and then using `HLOOKUP` for finding the values from the rows thereafter), but the problem is that the `HLOOKUP` command is *not automatically updated* with the new array (the array in which Member number 1001 is) (so my solution works for member 1000, but not for 1001 and 1002), and hence it always searches for the new value ONLY in the 1st Row (i.e. the row with the member number 1000).

I also tried reading the file with Python, but I am not well-versed enough to make much of a headway - once the dataset has been read, how do I tell excel to read the next 3 rows and get the (absolute) maximum in each column?

Can someone please help? Solution required in Python 3 or Excel (ideally, Excel 2014).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution will get you your desired output using Python.

I first `ffill` to fill in the blanks in your **Member No** column (`axis=0` means row-wise). Then convert your dataframe values to +ve using `abs`. Lastly, using `pandas.DataFrame.agg`, I get the `max` value for all the columns in your dataframe.

Assuming your dataframe is called `data`:

```
import pandas as pd

data['Member No.'] = data['Member No.'].ffill(axis=0).astype(int)
df = abs(df)
res = (data.groupby('Member No.').apply(lambda x: x.max())).drop('Member No.',axis=1).reset_index()
```

Which will print you:

```
   Member No.   X    Y    Z    A    B    C
0        1000  69   60   68   60   74   69
1        1001  78   55   89   78   92   87
2        1002  94  559  985  985  971  976
```

Note that I added extra columns in your sample data to make sure that all the columns will return their `max()` value.

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting a "NameError: name 'df' is not defined".

If it's useful, I have imported the table as an csv...

Here's my code ..................................    import pandas as pd # In[11]: data = pd.read_csv("TEST_database.csv") # In[12]: data # In[ ]: # In[ ]: # In[ ]: # In[ ]: # In[13]: df['Member No.'] = df['Member No.'].ffill(axis=0).astype(int) df = abs(df) res = (df.groupby('Member No.').apply(lambda x: x.max())).drop('Member No.',axis=1).reset_index() # In[ ]: # In[ ]:

Comment: Okay let me update my code. The error tells you that ```df``` does not exist because you are reading in the data and calling it ```data```, not ```df```. Please check my updated answer. Try the code again and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort you're putting in! 

It's still not working, unfortunately. This time, the following error ---- KeyError: 'Member No.'

Comment: Welcome. You have to put in the exact name of your column. What is your 'Member No' column called exactly?

Comment: I most definitely shall accept it as the correct answer once it works out :)

And yes, the exact name is indeed "Member No.". I rechecked too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227689/discussion-between-sophods-and-vikrant-srivastava).

Comment: For everyone else, the problem was in the reading of the data...it was reading as a single coloumn. The correct code for reading it is ....  data = pd.read_csv('TEST_database.csv',sep=';')